# how post method of form actually work behind scene

Tags: php, forms, post, get

I have used both get / post me and aware about the differences of both with regards to limitations / security and all.

Well,when we are using get method,we are getting data from query string and that is fine.

Now,for the post :

Let's say from one.php, we are passing variable name which is in form with method = "post" and we are getting it in two.php with $_POST['name'], where this name actually stored in between these 2 pages and from where it actually comes and one can able to get access it with $_POST?

Also, is there any chances for data being hacked / visible by / to anyone anyhow ?

Thanks!!

Comment: POST submits data to be processed (e.g., from an HTML form) to the identified resource. The data is included in the body of the request. This may result in the creation of a new resource or the updates of existing resources or both.

Comment: @Daan with a little extra explanation (and possibly a link) this could become an excellent answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value is stored in the request.

HTTP requests consist of a few key components.  Mainly:

- Address
- Headers
- Body

The key difference between a GET and a POST in this case is that a GET has no Body.  So any data you want to include in a GET needs to be included on the Address.  A POST, however, does have a Body.  And it includes the key/value pairs for the values in that Body.

Take a look at your browser's debugging tools and examine the requests/responses when interacting with the server.  For a POST request, you'll see that you *can* in fact inspect the values.  (Which you may want to consider when you talk about knowing the "security" of these requests...)

The values aren't "stored" anywhere special.  They work almost exactly like they do in a GET request.  They're simply in another part of the request format.

Comment: is there any structure to post and get method, to deep understanding?